# add tooltip for material-ui slider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui slider, I just wanted to know is their any option for adding tooltip inside the slider? I was not able to find any solution for it tries searching.
For Eg:

```
<Slider
      min={0}
      max={100}
      defaultValue={50}
      value={this.state.secondSlider}
      onChange={this.handleSecondSlider}
      tooltip={this.state.firstSlider}
    />
```

So that when the user drags the slider it shows the value on tooltip. I am still learning react. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can create your own Component `SliderWithTooltip`, you will use the Slider component and add your custom html for the tooltip

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem myself, here's a basic solution I put together that augments the Slider component, allowing you to pass in a label/tooltip element as a prop, styled however you like: https://github.com/tariqwest/material-ui-slider-label

Answer (score 0):

I created my own MarkComponent and put inside div with tooltip. Position it as you want. This positioning my not look good for you. Here is the code:

```js
import Slider, { SliderMark } from "@mui/material/Slider";
import { useState } from "react";

function CustomMarkComponent(props) {
  const { children, className, ...other } = props;
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <SliderMark
      onMouseEnter={() => setVisible(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setVisible(false)}
      {...other}
      className={className}
    >
      {children}
      {visible && (
        <span
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: -50,
            left: -40,
            width: 100,
            color: "white",
            backgroundColor: "black",
            borderRadius: 6,
            padding: "5 0",
          }}
        >
          Tooltip text
        </span>
      )}
    </SliderMark>
  );
}
```

And then use it inside SliderComponent:

```js
<Slider
  components={{
    Mark: CustomMarkComponent,
  }}
  ...other props
/>
```